# Thread.Sleep crashes my app

Tags: java, android, arrays, multithreading, serialization

This app talks to a serial device over an usb to serial dongle. I have been able to get it to process my single queries no problem but I have a command that will send multiple queries to the serial device and It seems to me the buffer if getting overrun. Here is part of my code:

This is my array with 20 query commands:

```
   String [] stringOneArray = {":000101017d", ":0001060178", ":00010B016C", ":000110017D",
        ":0001150178", ":00011A016C", ":00011F0167", ":0001240178", ":0001290173",
        ":00012E0167", ":0001330178", ":0001380173", ":00013D0167", ":0001420178",
        ":0001470173", ":00014C0167", ":0001510178", ":0001560173", ":00015B0167", ":0001600178"};
```

This is how I use the array:

```
getVelocitiesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ftDev.setLatencyTimer((byte) 16);
        int z;
        for (z = 0; z < 19; z++) {
            String writeData = (String) stringOneArray[z];
            byte[] OutData = writeData.getBytes();
            ftDev.write(OutData, writeData.length());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }
    }
});
```

Not sure the rest of the code is necessary but will add it if needed. 
So ftdev is my serial device. It sends the query command to the serial device, it receives the response in bytes, I use a For loop to build the response until all bytes (31 bytes per response) then I process that response and at that time it should receive the second query command from the array, so on until the last command is sent.. It is all fine an dandy if I allow the FOR loop to send only one or 2 queries but with a larger number of array index and it crashes. Figured I just slow down the FOR loop and add the thread.sleep but it freezes the app and crashes... What gives? Is there any other way to control the speed to which the commands are sent? I rather send them as soon as it is possible but I am afraid I don't know java as much. This has been so far my major stepping stone in finishing this personal project, been stuck for 2 days researching and trying solutions.

Comment: If the problem can be solved by pausing the output then you just need to put the work in a background thread. Everything you do in `onClick` that takes too long will "freeze" the app.

Comment: Please post your relevant log entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're sleeping for ~1000ms (well 950 to be exact because your last operation is not being sent to the serial device) plus the time needed to perform the writes over your serial connection.  That's a pretty long time to do nothing.  Remove the Thread.sleep(50) call and put the entire contents of the onClick into the run method of the following code:

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // talk to device here
    }
});
```

Then, ask a different question about the quick writes crashing your connection.

Comment: This fixed my problem as far as the gui not freezing. It still crashes the app. I used the thread.sleep and as long as I keep it on 350 and no lower it will run "fine" but I have the feeling you were leading me to a better solution. I have been reading the documentation for the api for the ftdi serial chip but I dont see there how I can control the i/o on the chip without loosing data... maybe more reading is next unless someone can tell me better... thanks david...

Comment: @Nandy what I was leading you to is asking a separate question regarding the IO with your ftdi serial chip.  You presented two issues in your question here and I elected to answer the easy one first.  You should accept this answer if it solved the initial problem then follow up with another question via "Ask Question" since the scenario is different now (app doesn't crash due to UI freezing, it crashed due to your serial communication).  Then people can more easily and directly help you solve that problem.  And, yes, I think there's some reading in your future (=

Comment: @Nandy also notice you're only sending 19 of the 20 commands to the device.

Comment: I realized my mistake once I ran the command successfully the first time. I will post about my I/O issues in another thread soon. Thanks for your help.